# Querying all data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, join

so I have three tables...structured like so

### A Location table

```
LocationID       LocationName

1                Location 1
2                Location 2
3                Location 3
```

### A Sub Area table

```
SubAreaID       LocationID      SubAreaName
1               1               SubName1
2               1               SubName2
3               2               SubName3
4               2               SubName4
```

### And a details table

```
SubAreaID       LocationID      UserName
1               1               Bob
2               1               Frank
3               2               Jeff
null            3               Dave
```

- Every location can have a sub area
- Every sub area can have details
- Every sub area must have a location
- Every details can have a sub area
- Every details must have a location

  Ideally, the result would look as follows. How would I structure the query?

  ```
  LOCATION NAME      SUB AREA NAME     USERNAME
  Location 1         SubName1          Bob
  Location 1         SubName2          Frank
  Location 2         SubName3          Jeff
  Location 2         SubName4          null
  Location 3         null              Dave
  ```

The thing that really seems to be throwing me off are the potential for nulls

```
SELECT a.LocationID, a.LocationName, b.SubAreaID, b.SubAreaName, c.UserName
FROM Location a
JOIN SubArea b ON a.LocationID = b.LocationID
FULL JOIN Detail c ON a.LocationID = c.LocationID
```

However, this does not produce the desired results. Any input/advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT a.LocID, a.LocName, b.SubAreaID, b.SubAreaName, c.UserName
FROM Location a
    LEFT JOIN SubArea b ON a.LocID = b.LocID
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT c.UserName 
             FROM Details c 
             WHERE a.LocID = c.LocID 
                 AND (c.SubAreaID = b.SubAreaID OR B.SubAreaId IS NULL)
    ) as c
```

**EDIT:** Try this query with [OUTER APPLY](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/).

Also check out this [**SQL FIDDLE**] (sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4bce/5ce/5) for a demo.

Comment: This is close. I get everything except for the Sub Areas that are null. That is...any "Details" that have a null sub area but a Location

Comment: @prawn I have updated the answer, however I am not able to add the fiddle as a link, so I added the URL instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of JOIN and FULL JOIN, replace those words with 'LEFT JOIN'.

JOIN requires that a location have a sub area to show up in results.

FULL JOIN will get data from both sides, even if there is NO matching value.